# beautifulsoup finding the before specific text data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried finding the text before string "半场控球率" using a find_previous function, but it seems not to work.

html code :

```
<div class="content">
            <table width="800" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#1381be">本场技术统计</th>
                </tr>                    
<tr><td width="295" align="right" class="bg1"><div class="barBg2"><div class="info" style="width:44%;"></div></div></td><td width="50" align="center" class="bg1">44%</td><td width="110" align="center" class="bg3">半场控球率</td><td width="50" align="center" class="bg1">56%</td><td width="295" align="left" class="bg1"><div class="barBg"><div class="info" style="width:56%;"></div></div></td></tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </div>
```

Python Code :

```
#coding:utf-8

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = """
<div class="content">
            <table width="800" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#1381be">本场技>术统计</th>
                </tr>
<tr><td width="295" align="right" class="bg1"><div class="barBg2"><div class="info" style="width:44%;"></div></div></td><td width="50" align="center" class="bg1">44%</td><td width="110" align="center" class="bg3">半场控球率</td><td width="50" align="center" class="bg1">56%</td><td width="295" align="left" class="bg1"><div class="barBg"><div class="info" style="width:56%;"></div></div></td></tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

print soup.find(string="半场控球率").find_next('td').contents[0]
print soup.find(string="半场控球率").find_previous('td').contents[0]
```

Code Result :

```
56%
半场控球率
```

Expected Result :

```
44% 
56%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
soup.find("td",text="半场控球率").find_next().contents[0]
soup.find("td",text="半场控球率").find_previous().contents[0]
```

you will get:

```
'56%'
'44%'
```